# Implementing of Apple watch board UI for Android

Tags: android, android-layout, apple-watch, android-viewgroup

I need implement a custom `ViewGroup` which seems like Apple Watch home screen with bubbles (there's a screenshot below)

[image]

The `ViewGroup` has to be scrollable in both directions and its children have to change their scale in depend of how close to the center they are.
I tried to implement this using `RecyclerView` with custom `LayoutManager`, where the first element is located in the center, and the others are around. But I stuck with it, when I try to achieve dynamically adding/removing of items during scrolling.
So, I need any help. Maybe somebody knows about existing solutions or has some clues. I will be glad to any help! I've also attached the source of my custom `LayoutManager`

```
class AppleWatchLayoutManager : RecyclerView.LayoutManager() {

    private val viewCache = SparseArray<View>()

    override fun generateDefaultLayoutParams() = RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    override fun onLayoutChildren(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler)
        fill(recycler)
    }

    override fun canScrollVertically() = true
    override fun canScrollHorizontally() = true

    override fun scrollVerticallyBy(dy: Int, recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler, state: RecyclerView.State): Int {
        val delta = scrollVerticallyInternal(dy)
        offsetChildrenVertical(-delta)
        return delta
    }

    override fun scrollHorizontallyBy(dx: Int, recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler, state: RecyclerView.State): Int {
        val delta = scrollHorizontallyInternal(dx)
        offsetChildrenHorizontal(-delta)
        return delta
    }

    private fun fill(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler) {

        val anchorView = findAchorView()
        viewCache.clear()

        val childCount = childCount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val view = getChildAt(i)
            if (view != null) {
                val position = getPosition(view)
                viewCache.put(position, view)
            }
        }

        var cacheSize = viewCache.size()
        for (i in 0 until cacheSize) {
            detachView(viewCache.valueAt(i))
        }

        fill(recycler, anchorView)

        cacheSize = viewCache.size()
        for (i in 0 until cacheSize) {
            recycler.recycleView(viewCache.valueAt(i))
        }
    }

    private fun fill(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler, anchorView: View?) {
        val anchorPosition = if (anchorView != null) getPosition(anchorView) else 0
        val xOffset = if (anchorView != null) {
            getDecoratedLeft(anchorView) + (getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(anchorView) / 2) - (width / 2)
        } else {
            0
        }
        val yOffset = if (anchorView != null) {
            getDecoratedTop(anchorView) + (getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(anchorView) / 2) - (height / 2)
        } else {
            0
        }
        var filling = true
        var round = 0
        var position = anchorPosition
        var scale = 0.9f
        while (filling && position < itemCount) {
            val sector = if (round == 0) 0.0 else 2 * PI / (6 * round)
            var angle = 0.0
            if (round == 0) {
                filling = fillRound(recycler, round, position, angle, xOffset, yOffset, 1f)
                position++
            } else {
                for (i in 1..(6 * round)) {
                    filling = filling && fillRound(recycler, round, position, angle, xOffset, yOffset, scale)
                    angle += sector
                    position++
                }
            }
            round++
            scale -= 0.1f
        }
    }


    private fun scrollHorizontallyInternal(dx: Int): Int {
        if (childCount == 0) {
            return 0
        }

        val currentRound = getCurrentRound()
        val roundsCount = getRoundsCount()
        if (currentRound == roundsCount) {
            val mostLeftChild = findMostLeftChild()
            val mostRightChild = findMostRightChild()

            if (mostLeftChild != null && mostRightChild != null) {
                val viewSpan = getDecoratedRight(mostRightChild) - getDecoratedLeft(mostLeftChild)
                if (viewSpan <= width) {
                    return 0
                }
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        }

        var delta = 0

        if (dx < 0) {
            val mostLeftChild = findMostLeftChild()
            delta = if (mostLeftChild != null) {
                Math.max(getDecoratedLeft(mostLeftChild), dx)
            } else dx
        } else if (dx > 0) {
            val mostRightChild = findMostRightChild()
            delta = if (mostRightChild != null) {
                Math.min(getDecoratedRight(mostRightChild) - width, dx)
            } else dx
        }
        return delta
    }

    private fun scrollVerticallyInternal(dy: Int): Int {
        if (childCount == 0) {
            return 0
        }

        // All views fit on screen
        if (childCount == itemCount) {
            val highestChild = findHighestChild()
            val lowestChild = findLowestChild()

            if (highestChild != null && lowestChild != null) {
                val viewSpan = getDecoratedBottom(lowestChild) - getDecoratedTop(highestChild)
                if (viewSpan <= height) {
                    return 0
                }
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        }
        var delta = 0

        // content moves down
        if (dy < 0) {
            val highestChild = findHighestChild()
            delta = if (highestChild != null) {
                Math.max(getDecoratedTop(highestChild), dy)
            } else dy
        } else if (dy > 0) {
            val lowestChild = findLowestChild()
            delta = if (lowestChild != null) {
                Math.min(getDecoratedBottom(lowestChild) - height, dy)
            } else dy
        }
        return delta
    }

    private fun fillRound(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler, round: Int, element: Int, angle: Double,
                      xOffset: Int, yOffset: Int, scale: Float): Boolean {
        var view = viewCache[element]
        if (view == null) {
            view = recycler.getViewForPosition(element)
            addView(view)
            measureChildWithMargins(view, 0, 0)
            val x = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view) * round * Math.cos(angle) + width / 2 + xOffset
            val y = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view) * round * Math.sin(angle) + height / 2 + yOffset

            val left = (x - getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view) / 2).toInt()
            val top = (y - getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view) / 2).toInt()
            val right = (x + getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view) / 2).toInt()
            val bottom = (y + getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view) / 2).toInt()
            layoutDecorated(view, left, top, right, bottom)
        } else {
            attachView(view)
            viewCache.remove(element)
        }

        val decoratedBottom = getDecoratedBottom(view)
        val decoratedTop = getDecoratedTop(view)
        val decoratedLeft = getDecoratedLeft(view)
        val decoratedRight = getDecoratedRight(view)

        return (decoratedBottom <= height && decoratedTop >= 0) ||
            (decoratedLeft >= 0 && decoratedRight <= width)
    }

    private fun getRoundsCount(): Int {
        var itemCount = itemCount
        var rounds = 0
        var coeff = 1
        while (itemCount > 0) {
            rounds++
            itemCount -= 6 * coeff
            coeff++
        }
        return rounds
    }

    private fun getRoundByPosittion(position: Int): Int {
        if (position == 0) {
            return 0
        }
        if (position >= itemCount) {
            throw IndexOutOfBoundsException("There's less items in RecyclerView than given position. Position is $position")
        }
        var elementsCount = 1
        var round = 0
        var coeff = 1
        do {
            round++
            elementsCount += 6 * coeff
            coeff++
        } while (position > elementsCount)
        return round
    }

    private fun getCurrentRound(): Int {
        var childCount = childCount
        if (childCount <= 1) {
            return 0
        } else if (childCount <= 7) {
            return 1
        }
        childCount --
        var round = 1
        var coeff = 1
        while (childCount > 0) {
            childCount -= 6 * coeff
            coeff++
            round++
        }
        return round
    }

    private fun findHighestChild(): View? {
        val childCount = childCount
        if (childCount > 0) {
            var highestView = getChildAt(0)
            for (i in 0 until childCount) {
                val view = getChildAt(i)
                if (view != null) {
                    val top = getDecoratedTop(view)
                    val highestViewTop = getDecoratedTop(highestView!!)
                    if (top < highestViewTop) {
                        highestView = view
                    }
                }
            }
            return highestView
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun findLowestChild(): View? {
        val childCount = childCount
        if (childCount > 0) {
            var lowestView = getChildAt(0)
            for (i in 0 until childCount) {
                val view = getChildAt(i)
                if (view != null) {
                    val bottom = getDecoratedBottom(view)
                    val lowestViewBottom = getDecoratedBottom(lowestView!!)
                    if (bottom > lowestViewBottom) {
                        lowestView = view
                    }
                }
            }
            return lowestView
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun findMostLeftChild(): View? {
        val childCount = childCount
        if (childCount > 0) {
            var mostLeftView = getChildAt(0)
            for (i in 0 until childCount) {
                val view = getChildAt(i)
                if (view != null) {
                    val left = getDecoratedLeft(view)
                    val mostLeftViewLeft = getDecoratedLeft(mostLeftView!!)
                    if (left < mostLeftViewLeft) {
                        mostLeftView = view
                    }
                }
            }
            return mostLeftView
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun findMostRightChild(): View? {
        val childCount = childCount
        if (childCount > 0) {
            var mostRightView = getChildAt(0)
            for (i in 0 until childCount) {
                val view = getChildAt(i)
                if (view != null) {
                    val right = getDecoratedRight(view)
                    val mostRightViewRight = getDecoratedRight(mostRightView!!)
                    if (right > mostRightViewRight) {
                        mostRightView = view
                    }
                }
            }
            return mostRightView
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun findAchorView(): View? {
        val childCount = childCount
        val centerX = width / 2
        val centerY = height / 2

        var anchorView: View? = null
        var minDistance = Int.MAX_VALUE

        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val view = getChildAt(i)
            if (view != null) {
                val distance = distanceBetweenCenters(view, centerX, centerY)
                if (distance < minDistance) {
                    minDistance = distance
                    anchorView = view
                }
            }
        }
        return anchorView
    }

    private fun distanceBetweenCenters(view: View, centerX: Int, centerY: Int): Int {
        val viewCenterX = getDecoratedLeft(view) + getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view) / 2
        val viewCenterY = getDecoratedTop(view) + getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view) / 2

        return sqrt((centerX - viewCenterX) * (centerX - viewCenterX) * 1.0 + (centerY - viewCenterY) * (centerY - viewCenterY)).toInt()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I've got a solution. Before the layout of elements I just define a collection of special models, which contains information about its position on the screen. Then, during scrolling I modify the collection, lay out elements which is on the screen now and recycle items, which is not on the screen. But there's a drawback: I have to pass an item size to constructor of manager to provide correct filling of children. The `itemSize` should be the same as defined in XML of item.  Maybe the solution is not perfect, but it works fine for me. Here's the code of `LayoutManager`.

```
class BubbleLayoutManager(private val itemSize: Int) : RecyclerView.LayoutManager() {

    private val children = mutableListOf<Child>()

    override fun generateDefaultLayoutParams() = RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    override fun onLayoutChildren(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        fillChildren()
        detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler)
        fillView(recycler)
    }

    override fun canScrollVertically() = true
    override fun canScrollHorizontally() = true

    override fun scrollVerticallyBy(dy: Int, recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler, state: RecyclerView.State): Int {
        val delta = scrollVerticallyInternal(dy)
        offsetChildren(yOffset = -delta)
        offsetChildrenVertical(-delta)
        fillAndRecycle(recycler)
        return dy
    }

    override fun scrollHorizontallyBy(dx: Int, recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler, state: RecyclerView.State): Int {
        val delta = scrollHorizontallyInternal(dx)
        offsetChildren(xOffset = -delta)
        offsetChildrenHorizontal(-delta)
        fillAndRecycle(recycler)
        return dx
    }

    private fun fillAndRecycle(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler) {
        val itemCount = itemCount
        for (i in 0 until itemCount) {
            if (i < children.size) {
                val child = children[i]
                val childRect = childRect(child)
                val alreadyDrawn = alreadyDrawn(child)
                if (!alreadyDrawn && fitOnScreen(childRect)) {
                    val view = recycler.getViewForPosition(i)
                    addView(view)
                    measureChildWithMargins(view, 0, 0)
                    layoutDecorated(view, childRect.left, childRect.top, childRect.right, childRect.bottom)
                }
            }
        }
        recycleViews(recycler)
        updateScales()
    }

    private fun recycleViews(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler) {
        val childCount = childCount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val view = getChildAt(i)
            if (view != null && !fitOnScreen(view)) {
                detachView(view)
                recycler.recycleView(view)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun fillView(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler) {
        val itemCount = itemCount
        for (i in 0 until itemCount) {
            if (i < children.size) {
                val childRect = childRect(children[i])
                if (fitOnScreen(childRect)) {
                    val view = recycler.getViewForPosition(i)
                    addView(view)
                    measureChildWithMargins(view, 0, 0)
                    layoutDecorated(view, childRect.left, childRect.top, childRect.right, childRect.bottom)
                }
            }
        }
        updateScales()
    }

    private fun scrollVerticallyInternal(dy: Int): Int {
        if (childCount == 0) {
            return 0
        }

        val highestChild = children.minBy { it.y }
        val lowestChild = children.maxBy { it.y }

        if (highestChild != null && lowestChild != null) {
            if (lowestChild.y + itemSize / 2 <= height && highestChild.y - itemSize / 2 >= 0) {
                return 0
            }
        } else {
            return 0
        }

        var delta = 0
        if (dy < 0) {
            delta = if (highestChild.y - itemSize / 2 < 0) {
                max(highestChild.y - itemSize / 2, dy)
            } else 0
        } else if (dy > 0) {
            delta = if (lowestChild.y + itemSize / 2 > height) {
                min(lowestChild.y + itemSize / 2 - height, dy)
            } else 0
        }
        return delta
    }

    private fun scrollHorizontallyInternal(dx: Int): Int {
        if (childCount == 0) {
            return 0
        }

        val mostLeftChild = children.minBy { it.x }
        val mostRightChild = children.maxBy { it.x }

        if (mostLeftChild != null && mostRightChild != null) {
            if (mostLeftChild.x - itemSize / 2 >= 0 && mostRightChild.x + itemSize / 2 <= width) {
                return 0
            }
        } else {
            return 0
        }

        var delta = 0
        if (dx < 0) {
            delta = if (mostLeftChild.x - itemSize / 2 < 0) {
                max(mostLeftChild.x - itemSize / 2, dx)
            } else 0
        } else if (dx > 0) {
            delta = if (mostRightChild.x + itemSize / 2 > width) {
                min(mostRightChild.x + itemSize / 2 - width, dx)
            } else 0
        }
        return delta
    }

    private fun offsetChildren(xOffset: Int = 0, yOffset: Int = 0) {
        children.forEach { it.offset(xOffset, yOffset) }
    }

    private fun updateScales() {
        val centerX = width / 2
        val centerY = height / 2
        val distanceMap = sortedMapOf<Int, MutableList<Int>>()
        val childCount = childCount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val view = getChildAt(i)
            if (view != null) {
                val distance = distance(centerX, centerY, view.x.toInt() + view.width / 2, view.y.toInt() + view.height / 2)
                val positions = distanceMap.getOrPut(distance) { mutableListOf() }
                positions.add(i)
            }
        }
        var scale = 1f
        distanceMap.keys.forEach { key ->
            val positions = distanceMap[key]
            if (positions != null) {
                for (position in positions) {
                    val view = getChildAt(position)
                    if (view != null) {
                        view.scaleX = scale
                        view.scaleY = scale
                    }
                }
            }
            scale *= 0.95f
        }
    }

    private fun distance(x1: Int, y1: Int, x2: Int, y2: Int) = sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)).toFloat() + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)).toFloat()).toInt()

    private fun childRect(child: Child): Rect {
        val left = child.x - itemSize / 2
        val top = child.y - itemSize / 2
        val right = left + itemSize
        val bottom = top + itemSize
        return Rect(left, top, right, bottom)
    }

    private fun fillChildren() {
        children.clear()
        val centerX = width / 2
        val centerY = height / 2

        val itemCount = itemCount
        if (itemCount > 0) {
            children.add(Child(centerX, centerY))
            if (itemCount > 1) {
                for (i in 1 until itemCount) {
                    fillChildrenRelative(children[i - 1], itemCount)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun fillChildrenRelative(anchorChild: Child, itemCount: Int) {
        var i = 0
        var direction = Direction.initial()
        while (i < 4 && children.size < itemCount) {
            val childX = anchorChild.x + (itemSize / 2) * direction.widthMultiplier
            val childY = anchorChild.y + itemSize * direction.heightMultiplier
            if (!hasChild(childX, childY)) {
                children.add(Child(childX, childY))
            }
            direction = direction.next()
            i++
        }
    }

    private fun hasChild(x: Int, y: Int) = children.any { it.x == x && it.y == y }

    private fun fitOnScreen(view: View) = fitOnScreen(getViewRect(view))

    private fun getViewRect(view: View) = Rect(
            getDecoratedLeft(view),
            getDecoratedTop(view),
            getDecoratedRight(view),
            getDecoratedBottom(view)
    )

    private fun fitOnScreen(rect: Rect): Boolean = rect.intersects(0, 0, width, height)

    private fun alreadyDrawn(child: Child): Boolean {
        val rect = childRect(child)
        val childCount = childCount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val view = getChildAt(i)
            if (view != null) {
                val viewRect = getViewRect(view)
                if (viewRect.intersects(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom)) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    private data class Child(
            var x: Int,
            var y: Int
    ) {

        fun offset(xOffset: Int = 0, yOffset: Int = 0) {
            x += xOffset
            y += yOffset
        }
    }
}


// Direction.kt
internal sealed class Direction(
        val widthMultiplier: Int, val heightMultiplier: Int
) {
    companion object {
        internal fun initial(): Direction = LeftTop
    }
}

internal object LeftTop : Direction(-1, -1)
internal object RightTop : Direction(1, -1)
internal object LeftBottom : Direction(-1, 1)
internal object RightBottom : Direction(1, 1)

internal fun Direction.next() = when (this) {
    is LeftTop -> RightTop
    is RightTop -> LeftBottom
    is LeftBottom -> RightBottom
    is RightBottom -> LeftTop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own custom ViewGroup subclass which will handle all the item resizing and scrolling.

No need to recycle views as you have a relatively small number of them.

Comment: For my case I have to provide smooth work with at least 1000 items (I need to show users list in this representation). So I think I need mechanism for recycling views, and that's why I chose `RecyclerView`